# Template and controller is not working in stateprovider

Tags: angular-ui-router

Route:

Here template and controller is not working. Below is code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('signup', ['ui.router']).config(appConfig);
    appConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider'];

    function appConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: true
        });
        $stateProvider
            .state('signup', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'app/signup/signup.html',
                controller: 'SignUpController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            });
    }
})();
```

Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('signup')
        .controller('SignUpController', SignUpController);
    function SignUpController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = "signup";
        console.log("signup controller");
    }
})();
```

HTML here

```
 <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>
```

console and title is not displaying. I don't know what is wrong here.

Thank you

Comment: hey, did you include <div ui-view></div> into your application. The template gets inserted into this ui-view.

Comment: No i did't include. I want signup when page loads.

Comment: can you try including <ui-view></ui-view> to your home page, and if nothing else, then directly to the body. Whenever you use ui-router, it tries inserting the template associated to a state, inside that "ui-view".

Comment: ya i tried its working. Thanks. :)

Currently getting error in controller

Comment: added the answer, just for the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was probably the absence of  tag, which is required by angular ui-router to insert any template associated to a state.

Adding the same solved the issue.